# Enable dragging between workspaces, Gnome-Shell

Tags: 11.10, gnome, configuration

I finally got around to installing Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop.  I played around with Unity for a while, but wasn't a fan, so I installed Gnome-Shell.  On my Ubuntu 11.04 machine I was able to drag a Window to the edge of the current workspace and have it switch workspaces.  How can I achieve this same functionality in Gnome-Shell?

Comment: Now with GNOME Shell 3.28.3 on 18.04 you can pres Super key and drag around windows between workspaces (also with ctrl+alt+shift+arrows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know Javascript, you can write an extension. Otherwise, AFAIK, there is no way to do this in GNOME Shell.

Comment: Bummer.  After some further research, your right.  This is disappointing, but I guess it is a minor change I have to deal with.  Thanks